# Kafka Twitter streaming TwitterException error

Tags: twitter, apache-kafka

I am trying the sample code on Kafka Twitter streaming from the following tutorial.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_real_time_application.htm

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.*;
import twitter4j.StatusListener;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

public class KafkaTwitterProducer {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      LinkedBlockingQueue<Status> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Status>(1000);


      String consumerKey = “XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX”; //args[0].toString();
      String consumerSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; //args[1].toString();
      String accessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ; //args[2].toString();
      String accessTokenSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ; //args[3].toString();
      String topicName = "twittertest" ; //args[4].toString();
      //String[] arguments = args.clone();
      String[] keyWords = {“Hello”,”Hi”,”Welcome”}; //Arrays.copyOfRange(arguments, 5, arguments.length);

      ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
      cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
         .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
         .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
         .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
         .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);

      TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

      StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

         @Override
         public void onStatus(Status status) {      
            queue.offer(status);

             System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() 
                     + " - " + status.getText());
            // System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreen-Name());

            /*for(URLEntity urle : status.getURLEntities()) {
               System.out.println(urle.getDisplayURL());
            }*/

            /*for(HashtagEntity hashtage : status.getHashtagEntities()) {
               System.out.println(hashtage.getText());
            }*/
         }

         @Override
         public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
            System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" 
               + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
         }

         @Override
         public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
             System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + 
                     numberOfLimitedStatuses);
         }

         @Override
         public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
             System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + 
                     "upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
         }      

         @Override
         public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
            // System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
         }

         @Override
         public void onException(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }
      };
      twitterStream.addListener(listener);

      FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery().track(keyWords);
      twitterStream.filter(query);

      Thread.sleep(5000);

      //Add Kafka producer config settings
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

      props.put("client.id", "SampleProducer");
      props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
      props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");     
      props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
      props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

      //props.put("key.serializer", 
        // "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
      //props.put("value.serializer", 
        // "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

      Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;

      while(i < 10) {
         Status ret = queue.poll();

         if (ret == null) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            i++;
         }else {
            for(HashtagEntity hashtage : ret.getHashtagEntities()) {
               System.out.println("Hashtag: " + hashtage.getText());
               producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
                  topicName, Integer.toString(j++), hashtage.getText()));
            }
         }
      }
      producer.close();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      twitterStream.shutdown();
   }
}
```

When I run this as Java application, I am getting the following error: (this is not compile/build error)

```
Read timed out
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1169356e or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=c04b39f0
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[1169356e-c04b39f0 c2863472-491bffd7], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:179)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:86)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.getFilterStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:346)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$8.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:322)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:552)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at twitter4j.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:35)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:143)
    ... 5 more
```

I am not sure what is the problem here. Could someone suggest me the solution or fix please?

Ok **Update** here: It is working now if key words are generic like  String[] keyWords = {"USA","Basketball","Sports};

If I change this to my requirement with specific keywords like my company name, product name etc., for ex:  String[] keyWords = {"XXX","YYY","ZZZ"}; then the java application is getting terminated. What could be the reason? How to fix it in this code? Please advise?

Comment: https://twittercommunity.com/t/unauthorized-error/66809 - you're unauthorized. Make sure your access tokens are all valid.

Comment: Unless you're specifically wanting to try out writing Java code with Kafka, check out https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-twitter for Kafka Connect twitter source to get the tweets into Kafka using just configuration files.

Comment: I have already given access token in the code. I didn't get why that's unauthorized?

Comment: To Robin, Please let me know, Why should not I use the sample from here: (looks like this is pretty simple example) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_real_time_application.htm

Comment: Ok Update here: It is working now if key words are generic like String[] keyWords = {"USA","Basketball","Sports};

If I change this to my requirement with specific keywords like my company name, product name etc., for ex: String[] keyWords = {"XXX","YYY","ZZZ"}; then the java application is getting terminated. What could be the reason? How to fix it in this code? Please advise?

Comment: @Stella - you can use the sample. It's up to you. I was just pointing out that there is an easier way to get data from twitter into Kafka than writing your own Java code.

Answer (score 2):

The Twitter4J source code shows that this exception is thrown because of Http connection time out.

I get similar exception by setting a low value for connection timeout.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
 .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
 .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
 .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
 .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret)
 .setHttpStreamingReadTimeout(10);
```

This is the stack trace I get.

```
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[1169356e-c3c3770e 1169356e-c3c376e4], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.6}
at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:179)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:86)
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.getFilterStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:347)
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$8.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:323)
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:554)                                                                           
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:137)
    ... 5 more
```

For your example, please try setting a higher value for HttpStreamingReadTimeout. The default value in the code is 40 seconds. Try setting it to 120,000 (milliseconds) or higher. That should work.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. Can you please help on this query too, I need Consumer sample for the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073518/deprecation-errors-with-kafka-consumer-for-twitter-streaming