# Deprecation Errors with Kafka Consumer for twitter streaming

Tags: twitter, apache-kafka

I've been working on Kafka twitter streaming feed data.

I'm following the sample from below link:
http://www.hahaskills.com/tutorials/kafka/Twitter_doc.html

I'm able to use Producer code and it is working fine. Able to get twitter feed and send to Kafka Producer.

I'm not able to use Consumer code, since it has been throwing as deprecated error for many APIs.

Here is the Consumer code:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import kafka.consumer.Consumer;
//import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
//import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
//import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;


//import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;

public class KafkaConsumer {
    private final ConsumerConnector consumer;
    private final String topic;

    public KafkaConsumer(String zookeeper, String groupId, String topic) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper);
        props.put("group.id", groupId);
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "500");
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "250");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");

        consumer = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(new ConsumerConfig(props));

        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public void testConsumer() {

     System.out.println("Test Con called");

        Map<String, Integer> topicCount = new HashMap<>();

        topicCount.put(topic, 1);

        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerStreams = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCount);

        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerStreams.get(topic);

        System.out.println("For");

        for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {

            ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();

            System.out.println("Size"+it.length());

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("Stream");
                System.out.println("Message from Single Topic: " + new String(it.next().message()));
            }
        }

        if (consumer != null) {
            consumer.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.println("Started");
     String topic="twittertopic";
     KafkaConsumer simpleTWConsumer = new KafkaConsumer("localhost:XXXX", "testgroup", topic);
     simpleTWConsumer.testConsumer();
     System.out.println("End");
    }    
}
```

It throws error : ConsumerConnector, ConsumerIterator, KafkaStream are deprecated.

ConsumerConfig is not visible.

Is there fixed version of this sample code (Kafka consumer for twitter)?

Comment: which version of kafka you are using?

Comment: kafka_2.11-1.0.0

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace & the Kafka jar version (Maven) to your question?

Comment: kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0.jar , kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar, kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar, kafka-streams-examples-0.10.0.0.jar, I am unable to build it, because of the errors mentioned in the actual question.

Comment: The project is uploaded here, https://ufile.io/no84b

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial you are following is very old and it's using the old Scala Kafka clients that have been deprecated, see http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#legacyapis

The classes that have been deprecated are:

- `kafka.consumer.*` and `kafka.javaapi.consumer` instead use the newer Java Consumer under `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.*`
- `kafka.producer.*` and `kafka.javaapi.producer` instead use the newer Java Producer under `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*`

Apart from using deprecated classes, your code was mostly correct, I only had to fix a few imports. See below a fixed version. Using it I was able to consume messages I was producing to a topic called `twittertopic`.

```java
package example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import kafka.consumer.Consumer;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;

public class MyConsumer {
    private final ConsumerConnector consumer;
    private final String topic;

    public MyConsumer(String zookeeper, String groupId, String topic) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper);
        props.put("group.id", groupId);
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "500");
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "250");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        consumer = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(new ConsumerConfig(props));
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public void testConsumer() {

        Map<String, Integer> topicCount = new HashMap<>();
        topicCount.put(topic, 1);

        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerStreams = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCount);
        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerStreams.get(topic);

        for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
            ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("Message from Single Topic: " + new String(it.next().message()));
            }
        }

        if (consumer != null) {
            consumer.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started");
        String topic = "twittertopic";
        MyConsumer simpleTWConsumer = new MyConsumer("localhost:2181", "testgroup", topic);
        simpleTWConsumer.testConsumer();
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

While the code above can be used, the next major Kafka release is likely to remove classes that are currently deprecated, so you should not write new logic using these.

Instead you should get started with the Java clients, you can use the examples provided on Github: https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples

Using the new Java Consumer, your logic would look like:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

public class MyConsumer {

    static final String TOPIC = "twittertopic";
    static final String GROUP = "testgroup";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", GROUP);
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);) {
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(TOPIC));

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1L));
                System.out.println("Size: " + records.count());
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    System.out.println("Received a message: " + record.key() + " " + record.value());
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End");
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried, but it is not retrieving the twitter data that pushed from Producer.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a version of your code fixed.

Comment: If i use KafkaStream / ConsumerIterator sample code, I am seeing ConsumerConfig, ConsumerIterator, KafkaStream, ConsumerConnector All are deprecated.

Comment: If i use new Java Consumer sample, it is not retrieving the twitter data that are pushed from Producer.

Comment: I've uploaded the entire project in ufile.io/no84b

Comment: I've observed now that even Producer code which I have for twitter feed is terminating after few seconds of data retrieval.

Comment: Do we have any other example similar to my case to test Kafka streams?

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue with the producer. The 2 samples I wrote above are able to consume messages from `twittertopic` fine for me. The 1st one is using the old deprecated API (like in your question) and the 2nd one is using the current API. 
You seem a bit lost and confused so I suggest you take time to run the examples I linked in my answer as well as the official quickstart (http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

Regarding Kafka Streams, it also has a quickstart: http://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/quickstart

Comment: Thank you. Could you please share your Producer code for twitter feed streaming, that way I can run both (Producer and new Java Consumer code) and test quickly and close this query.